# VB.NET Listview get line and remove

Tags: vb.net, listview

I was wondering how to get the first line of a listView set it to a string ( String Server = ) and then remove the string from the listview.

Comment: You might want to review [Ask] before you get any closer to any sort of ban.  Showing some thanks for answers by accepting some answers wouldn't hurt either,

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Server As String = listView.Items(0).Text
listView.Items.Remove(Server)
```